# How do I include editable Content Boxes in a Content Builder HTML Paste Email?

Tags: marketing-cloud

How do I include an editable content box in a Content Builder HTML Paste Email? We want to still leverage the HTML Paste, but have a content box that a nontechnical user can edit.

> Content boxes appear automatically in the email editor if you use one of the provided email layouts for your template, but you can also include them in your HTML paste templates. Content boxes do not automatically appear in the email editor if you are making an HTML paste email. http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_overview/content_boxes/#How_To_Store_a_Content_Box.c2.a0for_Future_Use

I have read that `<custom type="content" name="Content Box Name Here">`is supposed to retrieve the content box and  the content editor popup when you use the template but this is not working.  Even though I have a Content Builder Content block and call it in the code, nothing appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'custom' tag you referenced was/is for Classic Builder in SFMC.  Now to insert into a template a 'content block' you need to us a div tag like below:

```
<div data-type="slot" data-key="yourplaceholdernamehere">
```

The data-key would just be a description of the content area.  For instance you could put in "ContentArea1". Then you will be able to add a default content block into this container in the template editor and change/edit it when using it to create a new email.

There also is a spot in the template 'Code View' editor to insert snippets(the drop down symbol looks like **</>**). In that drop down find 'Content Area' and click that and it will drop the code into your template.

See below image (option highlighed in red)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  What do I input for data-key? I also do not see the option to add in Content from the code menu in Content Builder.

Comment: edited my answer to answer your question and to include image showing where to find Content Area inside code view of template

Comment: @Gortonington do you know if you can insert content areas for specific types of content? IE, if I wanted to lock down an area to image only?